# Как сделать так, чтоб на сайте можно было обрезать картинку (например как шапку в ютубе)?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, reactjs

Как сделать так, чтоб на сайте можно было обрезать картинку (например как шапку в ютубе)? Типа человек загрузил по высоте слишком большую фотографию и он может выбрать как её обрезать. Буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарен!!!

Comment: Есть много возможностей того, как обрезать картинку. Например можно использовать плагин ImgAreaSelect. Вот [ссылка](https://github.com/odyniec/imgareaselect) на их репозиторий

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно
::before
или
::after

Можно попробовать так

Comment: Можете дополнить ответ, а то не ясно, что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Я точно не знаю как эта фигня работает, но как то помню, обрезал с помощью нее картинку. Почитай про псевдоэлементы, очень удобная вещь для front-end`ов